# How to get push notification when a file is added

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm trying to open a push notification channel for changes for files. What I need is to get a notification for when a file is added. I know https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId/watch will give me notifications when a file is updated or changed. But I need a notification when a file is added so I don't know what the fileID is to open Files watch channel. 
If I use https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/changes/watch then I get a notification when a file is added but the "state" is "change" so I don't know if the file was added or the file was modified (I get the same state if the file is opened or added). Is there way to get notification only for new files being added to the drive?

Thanks
Al

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there way to get notification only for new files being added to the drive?

No but for each change that is a file, you can check to see if `createdTime === modifiedTime`. If they are equal then the file can be considered "new".

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that. But we have a big account with 1k users and 100k files I was hoping I could just look at the state and ignore the message if its not a new file.

Comment: Hi @AlA if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: This solution won't work for me. I'll try different options and once I figure it out I'll post it here. thanks

Comment: Hi @peter I'm trying your solution but when I try to get the file metadata using the fileID returned in the changes json response, in some cases I don't get the full metadata.So the creation and modification date is not there. { "kind": "drive#changeList", "changes": [ { "kind": "drive#change", "fileId": "0B4sYrHuuPrbTend", "removed": false, "time": "2016-12-12T19:50:47.487Z", "file": { "kind": "drive#file", "id": "0B4sYrHuuPrbTendBemFjN2Z0R0E", "name": "SOA Management Survey.doc", "mimeType": "application/msword" } }

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow @AlA. You should ask a question for this and supply code to reproduce etc Here's [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) which is a great resource.